# How to set a fixed height for an android dialog

Tags: android

I am writing a game, and using a dialog to show players available for play. I put a ListView inside the dialog, and when new players comes the items in ListView will increase, and when players leaves, the items in ListView will decrease. This makes the hight of dialog also changes.

How can I make the dialog a fixed hight, which can hold 3 items always?

Comment: Could you please post xml for your ListView and CustomDialog

Comment: if you can have at most 3 players, just use a vertical linear layout with 3 textviews- why complicate it with a listview?

Comment: The game is always played by two players. Yet I want a player to be able to select his opponent, from a pool of list which can be more than 3.

Comment: Krio: I am not using a CustomDialog. I called setAdapter() when I created the dialog, then the android framework will create a listView for me.

Comment: You can make the listview by yourself with a fixed height then add it as the view to the dialog.